# Convert a char list list into a char string list in OCAML

Tags: list, char, ocaml

I have an example:

```
val lst1 : char list list =
  [['l'; 'a'; 'n'; 'e']; ['p'; 'l'; 'a'; 'n'; 'e'; 't']; ['m'; 'o'; 'o'; 't'];
   []; []; ['s'; 'm'; 'o'; 'o'; 't'; 'h']; ['h'; 'a'; 'n'; 'g']; []; 
   []; ['c'; 'h'; 'a'; 'n'; 'g'; 'e']; ['w'; 'e'; 'n'; 't']; []; []; etc.]
```

What is a trick to convert this list into something like:

```
["lane";"planet";...]?
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you're wondering why you're getting downvoted, it's probably because this looks a lot like a homework assignment, and shows no sign of any effort on your part to solve it. Most people believe you should do your own homework. After all, that does seem to be the point of it. Please see [ask].

Comment: The best instructor knows how to deliver the message to the people who are less technical without giving out the solution. That was the purpose of my question. I am glad I did not use "I need a solution" in my question above. Thanks!

Comment: You're still expected to show some effort of having tried to solve it yourself, and to ask questions about specific issues. See point 3 here https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very compact implementation:

```
let to_str_list =
  List.map (fun cs -> String.concat "" (List.map (String.make 1) cs))
```

It looks like this when your call it:

```
# to_str_list [['h';'e';'l';'l';'o'];['w';'o';'r';'l';'d']];;
- : string list = ["hello"; "world"]
```

**Update**

If you want to suppress empty strings at the outer level you can do something like this:

```
let to_str_list css =
  List.map (fun cs -> String.concat "" (List.map (String.make 1) cs)) css |>
  List.filter ((<>) "")
```

It looks like this when you call it:

```
# to_str_list [['h';'e';'l';'l';'o']; []; ['w';'o';'r';'l';'d']];;
- : string list = ["hello"; "world"]
```

Comment: In my output, there are plenty of "". Is there a way to eliminate that? Thank you!

Comment: As of OCaml 4.08 this is a great place for `List.filter_map`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it,

```
let to_string l =
  let rec loop buf = function
    | [] -> Buffer.contents buf
    | x :: tl -> Buffer.add_char buf x; loop buf tl
  in
  loop (Buffer.create 100) l

let to_str_lst l = List.map to_string l
```

Alternate version of `to_string` without `rec` -

```
let to_string l =
  List.fold_left
    (fun acc e -> Buffer.add_char acc e; acc)
    (Buffer.create 100)
    l
  |> Buffer.contents
```

Sample usage in utop:

```
to_str_lst [['h';'e';'l';'l';'o']; ['w';'o';'r';'l';'d']];;
```

returns

```
- : string list = ["hello"; "world"]
```

Comment: Can I get away without using rec?

Comment: of course. You can use ``List.fold_left``` to implement loop() in to_string() function.